# What's the best way to validate multiple emails and handle errors in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, email-validation

In the current app I'm building I've got a textarea where a user will enter a comma-delimited list of email addresses.

I'm currently splitting the list into an array and then saving one by one.  But if, say, I have this input...

blah@example.com, test@example, foo@example.com

... then blah@example.com will be saved, but saving test@example will fail.  So I then need to remove blah@example.com from the comma-delimited string of values that I pass back to the textarea when I show the error that test@example isn't a valid email address.

Is there a better way to validate these on the server side and handle errors without getting fancy / ugly in the controller?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is a model that has_many emails, and the email model uses :validate_email, you could do something like the following:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :must_not_have_invalid_addresses

  ...

  def emails=(addresses)
    @invalid_addresses = []
    addresses.split(",").each do |address|
      @invalid_addresses.push(address) unless emails.create({:address => address})
    end
  end

  def must_not_have_invalid_addresses
    errors.add_to_base("Some email addresses were invalid") unless @invalid_addresses.empty?
  end

end
```

This provides a validation error + an array of the invalid email addresses which you can make accessible to your view if you like.

Answer (score 0):

ruby has a split function (.each) described [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html) and supports regular expressions as described [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html)

as such, you'd split the string (using "," as your separator) and then use the regular expression to validate each e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can put saving emails in transaction. Then if any save will fail, then all previos saves are canceled. In such case, validations can be done only on model layer.

I think it would be clear code, but for sure it isn't the fastest possible way (but using Ruby means you are not doing it in even fast way ;) )

Answer (score -1):

If you have them in a variable called `emails`, perhaps something like this may work:

```
  if valid_emails?(emails)
      # then have your normal logic here
      if @user.save
           flash[:notice] .....

      end
  end

  private
     def valid_emails?(emails)
        not emails.find {|email| email =~ /[\w\.%\+\-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9\-]+\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum)/i }.nil?
     end
```

EDIT: actually you may just want to use this regular expression. It was taken from the restful-authentication plugin.