# How would one validate the format of an email field in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a User model in a Rails application which has an email field. Is there a default validation that will ensure the email is in the correct format? If not, how would I go about validating that field?

Comment: by `valid email address` do you mean the email really exists, or it fits email format?

Comment: It's odd that this was closed. It may not be terribly specific, but I see a real question here.

Comment: @sscirrus Well, to be totally knit-picky, he didn't actually ask a question. Also, it's not good conduct to just ask for code handouts on SO. A more appropriate question would be "how would one go about writing code that does [desired outcome]?"

Comment: @MichaelDorst Fair point - while I do see a question in the text, I agree with you that SO isn't for code handouts.

Comment: @sscirrus As I said, I'm being knit-picky, but the OP simply **stated** what he was looking for, he did not **ask** a question. You may be able to **infer** a question from that statement, but the OP did not explicitly ask anything - hence: `closed as not a real question`. I agree with the five people who chose to do that because I feel that ill-formed questions can only lead to ill-formed answers, neither of which are helpful to this community.

Comment: I follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776907/what-is-the-best-easy-way-to-validate-an-email-address-in-ruby. 

I tested article post: http://my.rails-royce.org/2010/07/21/email-validation-in-ruby-on-rails-without-regexp/ by Ruby 2.1.0 and Rails 4.0.3 hosted into Heroku.

Comment: Here is the new way to do it: `validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Add in your gemfile:

```
gem 'validates_email_format_of'
```

and in your model:

```
validates :email, email_format: { message: "doesn't look like an email address" }
```

Or if you don't want use a gem, use regex:

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
```

Comment: The regex you provided doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: Use just: `with: /@/` https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/